# Why can't I change the $1 variable of the current environment using the source command with arguments

Tags: bash

Why can't I change the $1 variable of the current environment using the source command with arguments.Is there a way for me to internally change the positional parameter $1

```
script.sh
echo $1
echo $2
$ source ./script.sh Hello World
Hello
World
$ echo $1 $2
(nothing output)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "why"? You can't do it because it doesn't do that.

Comment: The source command executes commands in the current environment, so I assume that the parameters passed to the source command change the positional parameters of the current environment

Comment: Each stack frame has its own arguments. When the scope is exited, the stack frame goes away.

Comment: Does the source command create a new process and a stack? Isn't it executing commands in the current process? @Charles Duffy

Comment: @chenzhang, same process, new stack frame within that process -- just the same as how a shell function runs in the same process as its caller, but has its own local variables (if in fact it uses `local` or `declare`), its own argument list, &c. To be clear, it's the same stack (not a completely new one like it would be after an `exec()` or even a copy-on-write instance that can't modify the original like it would be with a `fork()`), just a new _frame_ added to that existing stack, and removed when the context exits.

Comment: Regarding "I assume that the parameters passed to the source command change the positional parameters of the current environment" - that would be a nightmare. You could then no longer write a script that sources a file and then loops on the arguments it was called with, for example, without writing some other code to save those arguments somewhere and then restore them after the "source", i.e. do what the current stack approach does automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `set` to set the positional arguments.

```
$ set -- Hello World
$ echo $1
Hello
$ echo $2
World
```

In a sourced script:

```
$ cat 3.sh
echo $1
echo $2
set -- "$@"

$ source 3.sh Hello World
Hello
World
$ echo $1
Hello
$ echo $2
World
```

Comment: (That is to say: If the OP didn't have "using the source command" in the question, we could just close it as a duplicate with one of our many preexisting questions on the topic having answers that tell people to use `set --` for this purpose and be done).

Comment: If they can change (or edit a copy of) the script, it's possible

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Yes, I ran it in a fresh terminal.

Comment: Also curious whether this is intentional behavior or an accident of implementation that could go away with a future bugfix.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Why surprised? That's what `source` does, runs the command in the context of the current shell.

Comment: Right, but it has its own arguments, and `set --` generally writes to the current stack frame's arguments; if you run it inside a function, you change only that function's arguments, not the arguments of the larger script or the context that _invoked_ that function.

Comment: Oh, I see now. `set -- "$@"` seems like a no-op....

Comment: (`source` behaves like functions in other respects as well -- see `return`'s behavior f/e)

Comment: So why can't arguments passed to source command change the external arguments when the source runs the command in the context of the current shell? @choroba

Comment: @chenzhang From documentation : `If any arguments are supplied, they become the positional parameters when filename is executed.` Notice `when filename is executed`